# Replacing my login form after successful login

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and it would be glad if I got help on this one. I want my login form to be replaced with "username" and the user's image. How can I achieve this. Below is my HTML form:

```
<li style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:12px">
              <div id="login">
                <form id="login-form" METHOD="post">
                <input class="form-control form-control-default" id="username" name="user" placeholder="username" type="text" style="height:25px; background-color:#fff; border: 1px solid #fff;">
            </li>
            <li style="margin-top:12px">                    
                <input class="form-control form-control-default" id="password" name="pass" placeholder="password" type="password" style="height:25px; background-color:#fff; border: 1px solid #fff;">                
            </li>
            <li><input type="hidden"  name="is_login" value="1"  /></li>
            <li style="margin-top:5px">
                <button class="btn btn-flat waves-button waves-effect" style="background-color:transparent" onclick="Alert.render('And you also smell very nice.');" type="submit" id="submit">Sign In</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </li>
```

Comment: There are many ways to achieve what you want... however, what is up with your mixing of `form` and `li` tags in your HTML snippet? What does that even render as?

Comment: the login form is on the nav bar which uses <li> to align the inputs

Comment: That may well be, but your snippet is not valid HTML - `li` elements should be children of a `ul` element (Which of course can be inside the `form`). Your first input has a closing `</li>` but no opening `<li>`, and your last input has no closing `</li>`. That's what I'm talking about, the HTML spec doesn't allow you to just pretend that `form` and `li` tags are equivalent.

Comment: Your code still has badly nested elements. Also, Starscream1984 kind of fixed your indentation for readability, why did you mess with it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a server side redirection from the login method as you are doing a form submit

Comment: this is the part of the code i wrote for the rediretion after succesful login`  $(this).fadeIn(200,function(){
                               //set timeout to hide response message
                               setTimeout(function(){
                     form.data('formstatus','idle');
                     
                     //redirect user to protected user page
                     window.location='/ads';
                               },3000);
                            });
              
               } else{`

Comment: could you elaborate little more?

Answer (score 0):

To handle sessions (logins and logouts), you'll need a server-side programming language. If you don't know any server-sided laguage yet, I recommend you to learn a popular one like PHP, Python, or JavaScript for server-side, like NodeJS or Meteor. If you need, [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com) has good tutorials for many of them!

[Here's a really good tutorial to make a simple todo list with session handling, in Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app). I really enjoyed this one.

[Here's a tutorial/example of session handling in PHP](http://www.ineedtutorials.com/code/php/creating-a-simple-login-script-with-php-and-mysql). I haven't read all of this; I've just googled "simple PHP login", checked if the code had a good readability, and searched for the term "inject" to check if its author was minimally concerned about security.

Before you actually use your code in your website, please read about [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/), specially if you are going to use SQL to authenticate your users (but still worth reading even if you're not going to use SQL). Also, learn HTML & CSS good practices, it'll save you time in the long run.